# Android MediaPlayer TTS Problem

Tags: android, media-player, text-to-speech

i use a MediaPlayer to play an audio file and the TTS-Engine to output a Text. No i want to set the volume of the two types to the same level. 
I have tried to set the MediaPlayers setVolume-Method and the more general setVolumeControlStream but with no effort. Has anybody an idea or sample code for that problem?

Fesp

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work but have you tried using the AudioManager class to retrieve the current volume, and then pass that volume into the TTS api. This is the way I approached a similar scenario.

I created my own custom Volume Manager (which is responsible for volume management between MediaPlayer/TTS/etc.) using the singleton pattern. I retrieve the MediaPlayer volume using the following.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Also, you will probably have to get a new instance of the AudioManager when the TTS is open because you will have make sure the Audio has hold of TTS and not the MediaPlayer. Sorry if this does not work, just a quick thought.

Then when you open up the TTS, you could change the volume manually, again by using the AudioManager api.

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(streamType, index, flags);
```

When the user changes the volume on TTS, the Volume Manager intercepts it and does its own process. I know this is not an ideal solution, but I used this as a quick workaround. When setting the volume, I had to get a new instance of the AudioManager to make sure I had hold of the TTS and not the MediaPlayer. Sorry if this does not work, just a quick thought.